# Solve complex equation $4\cos(z)+5=0$

Tags: complex-numbers

I'm trying to solve this complex value equation

$$4\cos(z)+5=0$$

Should I use the following?

$$\sin(z) = \frac{e^{\boldsymbol{\mathrm i}z} - e^{-\boldsymbol{\mathrm i}z}}{2\boldsymbol{\mathrm i}}$$
$$ \cos(z) = \frac{e^{\boldsymbol{\mathrm i}z} + e^{-\boldsymbol{\mathrm i}z}}{2}$$

Comment: Think of $e^{iz}$ are some new unknown $X$. The equation that you get is quadratic on $X$. Solve it with the quadratic formula. Once you have $X$, then $z=\frac{1}{i}\ln(X)$. I recommend to definitely not do what they recommended below $\downarrow$.

Comment: You could. But I recommend instead $\cos(x+iy)=\cos x\cosh y-i\sin x\sinh y$,

Comment: Tnx moonlight I will try it out :)

Comment: If I will say e^iz is some kind of x, then e^-iz will be -x?

Comment: @Xcompany $e^{-iz}=1/e^{iz}$ would be $1/x$. That is why the equation becomes $\frac{x+1/x}{2}=-\frac{5}{4}$, which is equivalent to the quadratic equation $x^2+\frac{5}{2}x+1=0$.

Comment: @MoonLightSyzygy oh right silly me tnx!

Comment: @MoonLightSyzygy oh its -5/4 so its +5x/2 right?

Comment: Yes, there should be a minus.

Comment: @MoonLightSyzygy great! tnx! :)

Comment: @MoonLightSyzygy Hey Moon, I got in the end x=-1/2 and x=-2

Comment: @MoonLightSyzygy log ( x ) when x<0 isn't defined

Comment: Yes, someone lied to you by way of not making you learn the complete sentence: There is no real number $y$ such that $\ln(x)=y$, when $x<0$.

Comment: Note that $-2=2e^{\pi i + 2K\pi i}$ for $K\in\mathbb{Z}$. Then $\ln(-2)$ can be any of the numbers $\ln(-2)=\ln(2e^{\pi i + 2K\pi i})=\ln(2)+\pi i + 2K\pi i$.

Comment: Similarly, $-1/2=\frac{1}{2}e^{\pi i + 2K\pi i}$, for $K\in\mathbb{Z}$ tells you that $\ln(-1/2)$ can be any of the numbers $\ln(1/2)+\pi i + 2K\pi i$, for $K\in\mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: @MoonLightSyzygy yeah its not my teacher's fault, I just need to listen more haha

Answer (score 1):

Note

$$-\frac54 = \cos z=-\cos(\pi-z+2\pi n)= -\cosh(-i(\pi-z+2\pi n))$$

which leads to $-i(\pi-z+2\pi n) =\pm \cosh^{-1}\frac54$ and the solutions

$$z = (1+2n)\pi \pm i\cosh^{-1}\frac54$$

Comment: Oh nice, I saw that on wolframalpha, now I know hot to get it. tnx!

Comment: Hey, 1 more thing, I solved it and got 1 answer, but how do I get the other one?

Comment: This is the one I got z = 2 π n - cos^(-1)(-5/4), n element Z
The another solution I need: z = 2 π n + cos^(-1)(-5/4), n element Z

Comment: @Xcompany - It may not be enough to express the solution as $\cos^{-1}(-\frac54)$, since $-\frac54$ is out of the domain of $\cos^{-1} x$